# Make a div on top another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the structure html like this

```
    <div class="main-row">
         <div class=""row-1">
         </div>
         <div class=""row-2">
         </div>
    </div>
```

row-1 & row-2 are like col-sm-6 grid system column in bootstrap.
Now i'm doing responsive I set both of them have width 100%, all I want is row-2 has to be on top row-1.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but your structure is wrong.

Comment: If you could provide more code (and fix your markup error with classes) in order to make testing easier we could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do it. Your solution is using CSS - flexbox property `order:`

On `.row-2` you write `order: 0`.

```
.main-row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.row-2 {
    order: -1;
}
```

---

--- EDIT ---

Another solution if you want to full invert the elements order is using `flex-direction: column-inverse`. e.g. instead of 1,2,3,4,etc... it will display etc,4,3,2,1

```
.main-row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-inverse; /*to display side by side use row-inverse*/
}
```

A quick demo here: http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/EydrLE

You can know more about Flexbox [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)